# Spring Boot application terminated with exit code 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Java and started a Spring application. However, when I instantiate a class in a different class and run a method the method does not output.

The class where the method is being called is SpringIn5StepsApplication.java and it looks like:

```
package com.example.springin5steps;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringIn5StepsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BinarySearchImpl binarySearch = new BinarySearchImpl();
        int result = binarySearch.binarySearch(new int[] {12, 4, 6}, 3);

        System.out.println(result);

        SpringApplication.run(SpringIn5StepsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The BinarySearchImpl class looks like:

```
package com.example.springin5steps;

public class BinarySearchImpl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int numberToSearchFor) {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

As the binarySearch method is being called, the expected output is 3, but instead nothing is output when I run the program. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the 3 to output to IntelliJ?

Comment: Use a logger (log4j) and @autowire an instance into your main class

Comment: are you getting any exception? or your spring boot application is starting successfully? @user

Comment: there are no errors when it runs, but it just outputs: "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: it's weird because i'm watching a video tutorial where it works

Comment: so which means errors run in debug mode or get the debug level logs and update here @Dog

Comment: this is my first Java program, i don't even know how to do that

Comment: i never worked with intellij, but post here whatever you have in console  @Dog

Comment: that's all there is in console: "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174612/discussion-between-deadpool-and-dog).

Comment: Why *in the world* is Boot involved here? Just scrap the `run` call and you'll get exactly the same behavior.

Comment: it's a tutorial on Spring boot

Comment: @Dog if this is your first Java app, it might be easier to start with basics and just develop a Java app with a main() method and get this working first. There's nothing in your example code so far that is using or needs Spring Boot. Once you've grasped some Java basics it will be easier to step up to Spring Boot next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Spring Boot`, the application is already leveraging many features of the `Spring Framework`. One of them is that you don't have to explicitly create instances of beans as it manages that using something called as `Inversion of Control (IoC)` which is also more commonly known as `Dependency Injection (DI)`. There is more information about that on that [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). You should modify the main method as follows -

```
package com.example.springin5steps;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringIn5StepsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringIn5StepsApplication.class, args);

        BinarySearchImpl binarySearch = applicationContext.getBean(BinarySearchImpl.class);
        int result = binarySearch.binarySearch(new int[] { 12, 4, 6 }, 3);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Also, make sure your BinarySearchImpl class has the `@Component` annotation as follows -

```
package com.example.springin5steps;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BinarySearchImpl {
    public int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int numberToSearchFor) {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

`@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Spring you are using Dependency Injection, so you don't need to create new instances manually, instead you should use `@Autowire`, in base of your description I saw that you are use `public static void main(String[] args)...` in both classes, **this is only used in the main class**, a simply solution is to remove the `main` method from `BinarySearchImpl`,  this should look like this:

```
package com.example.springin5steps;

public class BinarySearchImpl {
    public int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int numberToSearchFor) {
        return 3;
    }
}
```